# "strlen" giving different results in C

Tags: c, string

I have been learning about strings and the author of the book explained the given code. I didn't understand why it is giving **11 characters to name** and **31 characters to phrase of "PRAISE"** in the output?

INPUT

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* provides strlen() prototype */
#define PRAISE "You are an extraordinary being."
int main(void)
{
    char name[40];
    printf("What's your name? ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s. %s\n", name, PRAISE);
    printf("Your name of %u letters occupies %u memory cells.\n",
        strlen(name), sizeof name);
    printf("The phrase of praise has %u letters ",
        strlen(PRAISE));
    printf("and occupies %u memory cells.\n", sizeof PRAISE);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
What's your name? Serendipity Chance
Hello, Serendipity. You are an extraordinary being.
Your name of 11 letters occupies 40 memory cells.
The phrase of praise has 31 letters and occupies 32 memory cells.
```

According to my knowledge, it should give the output like this

```
What's your name? Serendipity Chance
Hello, Serendipity. You are an extraordinary being.
Your name of 11 letters occupies 40 memory cells.
The phrase of praise has 3 letters and occupies 32 memory cells.
```

Where I am getting it wrong?
Sorry if this is a stupid question!!

Comment: Why do you think "You are an extraordinary being." has 3 letters? I count 31, just as your program does.

Comment: Is this C style C++ or C ? Please fix your tags

Comment: The type of "character arrays / strings" is different between C and C++. Also the decay of char[] to pointer in sizeof is different.  Best to treat C and C++ as 2 different languages,

Comment: They are different languages

Comment: @Mike Seymour So why "Serendipity Chance" has only 11 characters not 18?

Comment: @Coldplay Because `scanf` reads *space delimited* words. So it reads `"Serendipity"` but not the space or the `"Chance"`

Comment: @Coldplay C'mon, it isn't that hard to figure out. Start counting from the beginning and see how far 11 characters takes you.

Comment: @Coldplay: Because `scanf` only reads a single word, stopping at the first space. It read "Serendipity", not "Serendipity Chance", as you can see from the program's output.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not different in any way that matters. The code is valid in both C and C++, and subtle differences between the languages don't matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's confusing you is that `scanf("%s", name);` only reads in data up to the first whitespace. In your name that is "Serendipity", which is 11 characters. `PRAISE` is the entire string "You are an extraordinary being.", which is 31 characters long (plus trailing '\0').

Answer (score 3):

The `strlen` function counts the number of character until a `\0`. You have

```
#define PRAISE "You are an extraordinary being."
```

which means that the preproccessor replaces every instance of `PRAISE` with `"You are an extraordinary being."`. The length of this string(returned by `strlen`) is 31 which is what the program prints in the second last `printf`.

The reason why `name` is being 11 characters long by `strlen` is that the `%s` in the `scanf` scans everything until the first whitespace character(like spaces,newlines etc). In your case, it scans `"Serendipity"` and stops scanning as the next character is a whitespace character(space). The length of `"Serendipity"` is 11.

BTW, the correct format specifier for `size_t`(the type that `strlen` and `sizeof` returns) is `%zu`.

Comment: So why "Serendipity Chance" has only 11 characters, not 18?

Comment: @Coldplay Read Joachim Pileborg comment on your question for that answer.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` computes the length of a string until a 0 character is met, not until a whitespace character. A 0 character is a char with value zero and it is not a visible character. Maybe that is what is causing your confusion. PRAISE is a string that consists of 31 characters and this explains the output.

On the other hand you read `Serendipity Chance` using `%s` which reads until a **whitespace** character. Thus only the first part(`Serendipity`) of this pair is read and it has length 11.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between functions `strlen` and `scanf`

Function `scanf` with format specifier `%s` reads characters from the standard input stream until a white space character will be encountered.
Thus if you entered

```
Serendipity Chance
```

this call of scanf

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

will copy in name only character `Serendipity`.

Function `strlen` counts characters until terminating zero will be encountered. For example the value returned by strlen for this string literal

```
"Serendipity Chance"
```

will be equal to 18 because in memory the string literal is represented like

```
Serendipity Chance\0
```

The same is valid for string literal defined with preprocessor constant

```
#define PRAISE "You are an extraordinary being."
```

Its size returned by `strlen` is equal to 31.

Comment: thanks buddy, I think I got it cleared now that the difference is occurring because of the reason that one is being used with scanf and other as a string.

Comment: @Coldplay The difference is how the functions process strings. You could get a more vvisible demonstration if you would try to use function sscanf (instead of scanf) and strlen with the same string containing several words.:)

Answer (score 0):

When you `printf("Hello, %s. %s\n", name, PRAISE);`
you clearly see "Hello, *Serendipity*." where "Serendipity" is `name`. And `strlen(name)` is right about it being 11 characters long.

The other part of the input string is not read because [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) reads a sequence of non-whitespace characters i.e up to the first blank char.